Given the distribution of the data, how to infer the parameters?
I have data, only discrete data points, and know how the data is distributed, i.e:
y = w * gamma.pdf(x, alpha1, scale=scale1) + (1-w) * gamma.pdf(x, alpha2, scale=scale2)

How do you accurately infer these five parameters?
My code are as follows:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde,gamma
data1 = np.random.gamma(4, 1, 200)
data2 = np.random.gamma(6,2, 200)
data = np.concatenate((data1, data2))
x=np.linspace(0,np.max(data)+2,800)
y=gaussian_kde(data)(x) 
initial_params = [0.5, 2, 1, 2, 1]  
params, params_covariance = curve_fit(two_gamma, x, y, p0=initial_params, maxfev=50000)
w, alpha1, scale1, alpha2, scala2 = params
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.histplot(data, bins=20, kde=False, color='y', label='Data density', alpha=0.5, stat='probability')
plt.plot(x, y, marker='o', linestyle='', markersize=1, label='Data distribution')
y_fit=w*gamma.pdf(x, alpha1, scale=scale1)+(1-w)*gamma.pdf(x, alpha2, scale=scala2)
plt.plot(x, y_fit, 'r-', linewidth=1, alpha=0.7,label='Mixture gamma distribution')
plt.legend(fontsize=8, loc='upper right')
plt.title("Expression distribution of gamma mixture")
plt.xlabel("Expression")

I use the curve_fit function to fit the form that does not yield a double peak, and I hope to be able to approximate the parameters of the function precisely. The use of neural networks and other methods are acceptable.
